# Media query in css not working for different width

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am learning media query at the moment.I am trying to give different width to the div as per the device width.This is the css i have done

```
.cont
{
  margin:auto;
  width:1200px;
  background-color:maroon;
  height:80px;

}

@media all and (max-width:480px)
{
  .cont{ width:400px; background-color:yellow; }
}

@media all and (max-width:768px)
{
  .cont{ width:700px; background-color:pink; }
}
```

I have included the meta tag as well

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

The problem here is that media query won't work for `max-width:480`.In the 480 and less resolution it still shows the background color of `max-width:768px` ie the pink color.

If i keep the `max-width:480px` query below  `max-width:768px` then the 480px will work and 768px won't.How do i make both work?

Comment: add a `min-width` for 768 @media query [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/41x65u8d/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add a min-width for `768` `@media` query

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/41x65u8d/

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    .cont {
        background:blue;
    }
}
 @media only screen and (min-width : 321px) and (max-width : 768px) {
    .cont {
        background:pink;
    }
}
```